# Constructor argument mismatch

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, ocaml

I've created a type for lazy binary tree:

```
type 'a lBT = LEmpty | LNode of 'a * (unit -> 'a lBT) * (unit -> 'a lBT);;
```

and wanted to create an instance of it:

```
let exlBST = LNode(3, function() -> LEmpty, function() -> LEmpty);;
```

but I received this error:

```
Error: The constructor LNode expects 3 argument(s),
   but is applied here to 2 argument(s)
```

Can you tell me what's going on? Isn't unit considered as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `LNode` is not parsed as you expect, a triple with two functions, but as a pair where the the second item is a function returning another pair. Use parentheses around at least the middle function, but preferably both for consistency, to make your intention explicit:

```
let exlBST = LNode (3, (function () -> LEmpty), (function () -> LEmpty));;
```

There are unfortunately a few of these weird parsing edge cases/ambiguities with OCaml's syntax. You'll learn to deal with it in time, but a good rule of thumb is: If in doubt, use parentheses (or `begin`/`end` when appropriate)